# need to download a PDF using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, pdf

i am trying to automate PDF downloading using Selenium Webdriver in python

but the problem is the download button was hidden inside a embed tag in HTML

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="www.abc.com/123.pdf" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="4" title="">
```

and the page would be like this [page view before download button view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjXva.jpg)

if i move the mouse over the top of the PDF

[after i move the mouse button over the top of the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJGOM.png)

i need to click on the download button but the element was not visible at first when i try to inspect its element by clicking f12 but when i inpect the element by right clickin on it, it will load the new separate HTML document  so i have no idea how to manipulate into that HTML any idea would be very helpful.

Comment: Doesn't looks like `WebElement` in `<embed>` tag is `hidden`. How do you conclude that? Share your code trials and the relevant HTML please.

Comment: i am sorry if i am not clear enough the embed is not hidden if you see the second screen shot there is download button on top left corner that button's element was hidden if i give F12 from the page it wont show that button's element it shows only if i right click that download button and click inspect on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using Selenium for this?

It is easy and efficient with Requests.

```
import requests
url='https://www.cs.uky.edu/~keen/115/Haltermanpythonbook.pdf'
page = requests.get(url) # get url

name = url.split('/')[-1] # to get filename
f = open(name,'wb')  # make a file object

f.write(page.content) # write data
f.close()
```

This gives you flexibility to download anywhere you want and is a lot faster than selenium.